# Seleccionar los valores más altos de un vector en java

Tags: java, vectores

Estoy aprendiendo Java. En un ejercicio de vectores tengo la siguiente consigna:
"En un vector de 23 posiciones se tienen las temperaturas máximas de las capitales de las 23 provincias argentinas en el último mes. A partir de esta información, un noticiero desea determinar el top 5 de las temperaturas más altas para poder mostrar en la pantalla de su programa, para ello se necesita un programa que sea capaz de recorrer el vector de temperaturas, determinar las 5 más altas y copiarlas en un nuevo vector de 5 posiciones"

Bueno, definí los 2 vectores y creo el scanner para el ingreso por teclado:

```
double temp[]= new double[23];
double max[]= new double[5]; 
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Hago la carga de las temperaturas:

```
for(int i = 0;i < 23; i++){
           System.out.println("ingres la temperatura");
           temp[i]= teclado.nextInt();    
        }
```

Ahora, en lo que tengo problema es en seleccionar las  5 temperaturas mayores.
Se me ocurre encontrar la mayor y cargarla en max[0]. así:

```
double maxim = -100;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < 5; j++){
           if(temp[j] > maxim){
               maxim = temp[j];
              
           }
   
        }
         max[0] = maxim; 
    }
```

Y luego repetir la operción 5 veces comparando con maxim y el valor anterior(max[1] > maxim pero < a max[0]).... Algo así, pero no me sale o no sé como hacerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente podridas usar un método de ordenamiento como burbuja o Arrays.sort esto para ordenar ascendentemente los valores de tu array y tomar los 5 últimos los cuales representaran los mayores valores ingresados..pero a modo de practica te planteare algo basado en tu código

lo primero es recorrer el array donde guardaras los 5 mayores valores

```
for (int i=0;i<max.length;i++ )
```

y dentro de este recorrer el array donde estan todos los valores ingresados esto para obtener el valor maximo en cada iteracion

```
 for (int j=0;j<temp.length;j++ )
```

la condicional sera la misma que planteaste

```
double mayor=0;
int x=0; //x almacenara el indice del mayor

for (int i=0;i<max.length;i++ ) {//recorremos el array max
    
   for (int j=0;j<temp.length;j++ ) {//recorremos el array temp
    
         if(temp[j]>mayor){
            mayor=temp[j];
            x=j;//guardamos el indice del mayor
         }

   }

   temp[x]=0; //cambiamos el valor del mayor valor para que no aplique en la siguiente iteracion y pueda cojer el anterior numero mayor y asi sucesivamente
   max[i]=mayor; //guardamos el primer elemento mayor
   mayor=0;//limpiamos la variable que almacena el mayor

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Al principio no entendía por  qué ```temp[x]=0;```. Pero al final entendí: haces "desaparecer" la primera temperatura máxima para que a la siguiente iteración saque la segunda máxima y así sucesivamente.